# Magento 2.2 css override is not working

Tags: overrides, magento2.2.2, less-css

I am new to Magento 2 development and am stuck on changing the .header .content CSS class. I have tried by creating a _theme. less file inside my local theme but the CSS is not overriding.

Can you please suggest to me how to override some of the existing CSS inside my local theme? My theme is inherited from a blank theme.

Thanks in advance to all of you.

Answer (score 0):

Override below css in your theme :

> /vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_module.less

Your Theme

> /app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourTheme/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_module.less

Now you can apply your changes in your theme

Comment: Have you tried above way ?

Comment: No, I will try and let you know.Thanks for your help and support.

Comment: Hi ,I have tried your solution but my css not overrides the existing one.

Comment: @SanjaySatapathy could you please share with me your file structure

Comment: app/design/frontend/Pixel/Porto/web/css/source/_module.less

Comment: No, it's wrong, you have missed to create "Magento_Theme" folder

Comment: you should created like this : app/design/frontend/Pixel/Porto/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_module.less

Comment: Hi I have tried with your struture also but still no lucks

Comment: Inside module.less I have added below code

Comment: .navigation{background:black;}

Comment: if you need change in navigation then you should override navigation.less file not module.less

Comment: please read https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-inherit.html for override

Answer (score 0):

Create the following file

```
app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/web/css/source/_extend.less
```

Add your css in **_extend.less** file.

Then run following CLI command.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Comment: I have already tried this approach but still the issue persists .I have crated _extemd.less file inside the defined path you mentioned but the css not overriding

Comment: Using inspect element, check in the browser if any other css is overriding this or not?

Comment: Hi Dinesh ,I have already checked in the console and I can't able to see my modified css.also I have checked inside style-l.css inside pub/static folder

Comment: Yes, because you haven't compiled and executed _extend.less file using grunt.

Comment: In extend.less, for change header color, @header-panel__background-color: @color-red10; not working, any hep thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your css file in default.xml in your theme like below :

Path : app/design/frontend/{Packaname}/{themename}/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>    
        <css src="Magento_Theme::css/custom.css"/>      
    </head>
</page>
```

In css file you can override styling by marking it !important like below :

```
.header
{
    font-size: 18px !important;
}
```

Comment: It's not correct way to use !important because magento provide us less for header css

Comment: Yes,I need only to override some css classes of parent theme without using ! important.else it will again cause  problem for responsiveness.

Comment: Okay, if nothing works, do try this.